# node app 404 when trying to transfer to iisnode

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, iisnode

I am trying to transfer a nodejs app from my development machine to our IIS server. It runs perfectly fine on my machine but I am always getting 404s when I transfer it to IIS.

The directory structure is like so:

```
C:\Programs Files\iisnode\wwww
└ mysite
  ├ public
  │ ├ app
  │ ├ css
  │ ├ js
  │ └ index.html
  ├ web.config
  └ server.js
```

When I go to: `localhost/node/mysite` I get a 404.

Here is the contents of my `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>

        <!-- Tell iisnode where node.exe is located -->
        <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"/>

        <!-- Redirect all requests to server.js -->
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried updating my express routes by prefixing them with `node/mysite` but that hasn't worked.

I can tell that node is receiving requests because I have it set up to log all requests and there is the following in the log files:

```
Server started on //.pipe/<some long code>
GET /node/mysite
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Was this resolved? I am facing similar issue